# Shell script invoking python code to be run in a virtualenv from Crontab

Tags: python, shell, cron

I need to run a python script from a virtual environment. This will be run from s shell script which in turn will be called from Crontab scheduler.

I am not able to activate the environment when the shell script is called from Crontab

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but try and put this in a shell script:

```
cd ~/<path>
source <env>/bin/activate
python <script>.py
```

Comment: I did this and it works fine when I source the shell script. But when called from a crontab it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Activate your virtualenv to identify the interpreter path:

```
workon myVenv1
which python
/home/www-user/virtualenvs/myVenv1/bin/python
```

So the cronjob should look like this:

```
* * * * * /home/www-user/virtualenvs/myVenv1/bin/python <full_path_to_script>
```